# Get all possible english words from a string

Tags: python, string, nltk

Generate all possible combination of english words from a given string in python.

Input: godaddy
Output: go, god, dad, add, daddy

Any good libraries?

Comment: Looks to me you want to use a *trie* (not to be confused with *tree*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `enchant` from http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html

```
>>> from nltk import everygrams
>>> import enchant
>>> word = 'godaddy'
>>> [''.join(_ngram) for _ngram in everygrams(word) if d.check(''.join(_ngram))]
['g', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'y', 'go', 'ad', 'god', 'dad', 'add', 'daddy']
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
# Exclude single char words.
>>> [''.join(_ngram) for _ngram in everygrams(word) if d.check(''.join(_ngram)) and len(_ngram) > 1]
['go', 'ad', 'god', 'dad', 'add', 'daddy']
```

But if it's all combinations of strings, regardless of whether it's a valid English word:

```
>>> list(everygrams(word))
```

See also:

- [n-grams in python, four, five, six grams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531684/n-grams-in-python-four-five-six-grams)
- [Generating Ngrams (Unigrams,Bigrams etc) from a large corpus of .txt files and their Frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441605/generating-ngrams-unigrams-bigrams-etc-from-a-large-corpus-of-txt-files-and-t)
- [extracting n grams from huge text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676448/extracting-n-grams-from-huge-text)
- [Fast/Optimize N-gram implementations in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883108/fast-optimize-n-gram-implementations-in-python)
- [How to compute skipgrams in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847682/how-to-compute-skipgrams-in-python)

---

## Note

Any dictionary checking method would have its limitation:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import words as english
>>> vocab = set(w.lower() for w in english.words())
>>> "google" in vocab
False
>>> "stackoverflow" in vocab
False

>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.check('StackOverflow')
False
>>> d.check('Stackoverflow')
False
>>> d.check('Google')
True
```

The "principled" way to do this task is to do language modeling at character level and have some probabilistic way to check whether the sequence of characters is more/less probable as English words.

Also, there are many Englishes in the world. A "valid" word in British English could be an unknown word in American English. See http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/projects/ice.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Englishes#Classification_of_Englishes

Comment: What about `oda`, `da` or `od`?

Comment: Don't think they are valid "English" words =)

Comment: Yes they are. They are abbreviations.

Comment: Cringing... But there're surely better spellcheckers than `enchant`, the solution still remains to generate ngrams and then check through a spellchecker.

Comment: Yes but it's not that efficient when you can get all the words using `nltk.corpus`.

Comment: @Kasramvd Abbreviations aren't valid English words.

Comment: @NickA If by valid you mean meaningful they are or if you mean they exist in dictionary still they are. If you don't want to count them you should probably mention that.

Comment: @Kasramvd If we take a word to mean a valid play in scrabble, abbreviations including acronyms such as oda are not words.

Comment: @alvas How did the word got split? You missed a line maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nltk.corpus.words` to create a set of all English words, then  find the intersection of all possible words generated from your string with the English words:

```
In [56]: all_words = {st[i:j + i] for j in range(2, len(st)) for i in range(len(st)- j + 1)}

In [57]: english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())

In [58]: english_vocab.intersection(all_words)
Out[58]: {'ad', 'add', 'addy', 'da', 'dad', 'daddy', 'go', 'god', 'od', 'oda'}
```

Note that the words like `OD` or `oda` are valid abbreviations.

Comment: Good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a set of all English words. I expect there are many libraries that can do this, but recommendations for software libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so just use whatever you can find.

Then, iterate through all substrings of the string, and see if any of them are in the collection.

```
words = #???
s = "godaddy"
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
        substring = s[i:j+1]
        if substring in words:
            print(substring)
```

Result:

```
go
god
od
oda
da
dad
daddy
ad
add
```

Comment: Execution time is large.